# C Preprocessor #define What type is the declared variable?

Tags: c, constants, c-preprocessor

When I define a numerical constant with `#define` (e.g. `#define pi 3.141593`) is it an `int`, `float`, `double` or what?

Comment: constant value as double, not variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define it it's none of those.
The Preprocessor will look for `pi` in your code and replace that with the `3.141593` before attempting to actually compile the code.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion):

> Whenever the identifier appears in the source code it is replaced with the replacement token list, which can be empty.

The type will be defined by the context in which you use that macro.

Comment: ty and thx to everyone who came here to help me

Answer (score 4):

Neither. It is a lexicographical replacement, that is, it will replace **pi** with **3.141593** wherever it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

All the preprocessor does for this `#define` macro is text substitution, it has no idea what type `pi` is.

The type of `pi` here is determined by `3.141593`, which is a literal of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

After preprocessing, the macro `pi` will be replaced with the literal `3.141593`, and floating point literals have type `double`.  If you want a literal to have type `float`, then you must add an `f` suffix - thus, the literal `3.141593f` will have type `float`.

Answer (score 0):

The `#define` does not have any concept of data types. It defines simply a textual replacement by the preprocessor.

The compiler will then see the replaced text and determine the type of the constant according to the [rules](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4) given by the C standard.